# Trigger and Event from within jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I am looking at the possibility for an AutoCheck style jQuery HTML application that every 5 second it goes off the a DB and checks some data.

That is the easy part, which I can do.

Now what I would like is to have an AutoCheck time going, something like

```
var t = setTimeout("autocheck()", 5000);
```

So every 5 seconds it is triggered, and I would like it to raise an event.

The reason for this is so on other pages which include this feature can monitor that event and if raised do a task, the task the new page will do I don't care, just as long as the AutoCheck event is raised and the task is performed.

Any additional HTML / jQuery code with the page may also require to use the AutoCheck to perform another action based on the event.

So in short I need an AutoCheck to raise an event and for multiple listeners to trigger a process when that event is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using what you've got...

Ajax calls already raise events. Why not use one of those? For instance, you could always bind logic to:

```
$.ajaxStart(function(){
  $(".msg").html("New Request Started.");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

#### Adding what you need...

If you find the present ajax events to be insufficient, you can create completely new events. I would suggest taking a look at the following question: [How to dynamically register to jquery custom events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271942/how-to-dynamically-register-to-jquery-custom-events)

Comment: Yes the link provided works a treat, I'm using 

$.ajaxStart(function() {
     $.event.trigger('customAjaxStart');
});

Many thanks